# Get the calling object of an instanced constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, reference, nested

I'm not sure if the title did this justice, but here is what I have...

```
function A() {};

A.prototype.B = function(){
   this.backref = //??  --  should be set to "a"
};

var a = new A();  // specialized factory...

var b = new a.B();  // instantiate an "a" specialized version of B
var zztop = b.backref instanceof A; //would be true
```

I need to assign backref to the instance "a" that called the B constructor. How can I do this? I've looked through all the properties in Chrome debugger, and am not even sure it is possible. Anyone know how to do this? I need to do this because I need access to variables stored in "a". Or is there a better way to do something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this just using the properties given to you, but you can always make the backref one of the arguments to the `B` constructor:

```
A.prototype.B = function(backref) {
    this.backref = backref;
}

var a = new A();
var b = new a.B(a);
```

Ugly, but it works.

Comment: I don't want to do that cause it will make me have to type more when I initialize the objects, lol.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called inheritance. You want object B to inherit the properties of object A.

```
function A() {
  this.length = 3;
}

function B() {
  this.height = 5;
}

B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B;

var obj = new B();

obj.height;  // returns 5
obj.length;  // returns 3
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6QeT/